# Understanding fuel tanks/pumps of Fighter jet

Tags: fighter, jet, fuel-systems, fuel-tanks

I have observed fighter jets performing maneuvers like inverting, Turing around in sharp angles etc. This may subject plane to G forces and other dynamic forces. How does fuel tank ensure steady delivery of fuel to engines in such dynamic conditions.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1183/do-fighter-jets-have-a-traditional-inverted-fuel-system

Comment: Thanks a lot @WPNSGuy

Answer (score 1):

Most tactical fighter aircraft have negative and zero G time limits (on the order of approximately 10-30 seconds) reduce the risk of fuel starvation and ensure proper circulation of oil.  For this reason, and because it is far more comfortable on the human body, most maneuvers are done at positive G.

Most aircraft keep positive pressure in the tanks via bleed and ram air to to ensure proper feeding of the pumps.  Any system based on pressure and gravity at 1 G should function as well at higher positive G loads.  It's really zero or negative Gs that present problems.

Demonstration aircraft like the Blue Angels who may spend more time inverted at -1G are fitted with special swiveling pickups to ensure fuel and oil can keep moving where they need to go.

Comment: Under Positive G how does it ensure that pump always have access fuel, in previous comment it was mentioned about air pressuring the fuel. Can you elaborate little bit on that as well?

Comment: I added the middle paragraph, please let me know if that clears anything up.  Really any more detail would probably be aircraft specific.

Comment: Thanks a lot this explains really well